# I want to make <input> italic. How to do it?

Tags: javascript, html

I want make text in the input tag italic. Help me please!

I try it:

```
<input type="text" id="Test"/>
```

JS:

```
let test = document.getElementById("Test")

test.value = "<i>Foo</I>"
```

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `font-style: italic;` in the CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#test{
font-style : italic;
color : blue;
}
```

```html
<input id='test' type='text'/>
```

Output :

[image: Output of above code]